# Gmap4Rails specific location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'geolocation'} }, function(){
if(navigator.geolocation)
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
});

function displayOnMap(position){
var marker = handler.addMarker({
lat: position.coords.latitude,
lng: position.coords.longitude
});
handler.map.centerOn(marker);
};
```

I can get my current location on the screen by this way. How can I get the specific location that all clients will see the same adress.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying one specific location using Google map API, I think you can work directly with the HTML/CSS portion of your Rails app, insead of having to add a gem.

See this tutorial - https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

and just follow the Rails MVC structure to put your code in the right files. This should also be relatively easier since you have already worked with Geocoder and Gmaps4rails.